# FlipView with variable controls

Tags: winrt-xaml

I want to present images (given as a collection of `StorageFile`s) in a `FlipView`.
Images are in a custom format and decoded by:

```
async Task<WritableBitmap> MyDecodeImage(StorageFile sf) { ... }
```

The `WritableBitmap` can be assigned to `image.Source`.
There can be hundreds of files so they should be decoded on demand rather than all at once.

How to declare my `FlipView`? It should normally show `Image`s, but for files that have decoding errors it should show an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use lots of code behind and the [`ContainerContentChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.containercontentchanging.aspx) event to start/cancel loading the images. Use a prioritized list to make sure you first load an image for the currently visible item rather than something that's virtualized to show something soon. Use [`StorageFile.GetThumbnail()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync.aspx) rather than loading the entire image until you zoom in on the image to use less memory and speed up loading time, especially after the system has already cached the thumbnail.

Once the decoding task is complete - you can write code to specify what should show up in a `FlipViewItem`.

Comment: How's `StorageFile.GetThumbnail()` going to give anything interesting if the files are in a format that is unknown to Windows?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question as being about performance. It is not. I know I can put an `Image` in `FlipView.ItemTemplate`. What I ask is how to show `Image` for some items and a `TextBlock` for others?

Comment: Have both of them in XAML with `Visibility="Collapsed"` and switch to `Visibility.Visible` on the one you want to become visible. Put a `UserControl` in `ItemTemplate` to be able to run code per specific item.